# Glide Record query

Tags: include, servicenow

I am trying to build a custom application where in a table I have two fields role and rates.

The table has three different row value. I am trying script include as glide record is not good way for custom application and I need to fetch the values like SQL query.

```
Select  rates from the table where role ='x'
```

and run this query to get all values in 3 different variable.

1. I am trying to use GlideRecord in the scope application but getValue(); is returning (null) value

   ```
   var role = new GlideRecord ('x_estimation_offsh_india_rates');
   x= role.getValue('roles');
   gs.info(x);`
   ```

   What's wrong here ??

   I even tried get() but not working as I cannot use this for  all the values in the tables

   ```
   var x;
   var role = new GlideRecord ('x_estimation_offsh_india_rates');
   role.get('role','it1');
   x=role.rates;
   gs.info(x);`
   ```
2. Also as the query result should be in  3 different variable I need some help how to multiple return values in script include

Answer (score 1):

First, I should mention that a lot of what you're doing goes against best practice a little bit, so I'm going to recommend having a look at my books: Learning ServiceNow (http://lsn.sngeek.com), and The ServiceNow Development Handbook (http://handbook.sngeek.com).

That said, the problem is that you never call the .query() or .next() methods.

After declaring your GlideRecord variable and adding any filter conditions, call the .query() API to perform the query. Then, calling .next() populates your GlideRecord variable with the values from the first returned record. It returns a Boolean indicating whether a record was found, so you can use it as a condition of a while loop to iterate over all returned records:

```
while(gr.next()) { /*do stuff*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to print all

```js
var ratesGr = new GlideRecord ('x_estimation_offsh_india_rates');
ratesGr.query();
while(ratesGr.next()){
   var x = ratesGr.getValue('roles');
   gs.info(x);
}
```

if you want to fetch one record

```js
var ratesGr = new GlideRecord ('x_estimation_offsh_india_rates');

if(ratesGr.get('d3e87e9d73d91300cbb654eb7df6a7a5')){ // sys_id of the record
   var x = ratesGr.getValue('roles');
   gs.info(x);
}
```

Useful links:

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/kingston-application-development/page/script/server-scripting/concept/c_UsingGlideRecordToQueryTables.html

https://www.servicenowguru.com/scripting/gliderecord-query-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the `query()` method. Use the following:

```
var obj=[];
var record = new GlideRecord ('x_estimation_offsh_india_rates');
record.query();
while(record.next()){
   obj.push({
     "role":record.getValue("role"),
     "rate":record.getValue("rates"),
   });
}
gs.info(obj);
```

So, if you have a table like this:

```
role | rate
  x     1
  y     2
  z     3
```

The object should look like this:

```
obj = [
  {"role":"x", "rate":1},
  {"role":"y", "rate":2},
  {"role":"z", "rate":3}
]
```